# Please help me on this javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

Here is my script:

```
function createSummaryAndThumb(pID) {
var div = document.getElementById(pID);
var imgtag = "";
var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
var summ = summary_noimg;
if(img.length >= 1) {
    imgtag = '<span class="thumbnail pull-left"><img src="' + img[0].srcreplace('/s640/', '/s' + image_size + '/') + '" width="' + img_thumb_width + 'px" height="' + img_thumb_height + 'px"/></span>';
    summ = summary_img;
}

var summary = imgtag + '<p>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML, summ) + '</p>';
div.innerHTML = summary;
}
```

The above script will replace /s640 with /image_size. But what can i do so that it change any value of the portion '640'. I've tried this but it won't worked-

```
function createSummaryAndThumb(pID) {
var div = document.getElementById(pID);
var imgtag = "";
var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
var summ = summary_noimg;
if(img.length >= 1) {
    if (uh>img_thumb_width) imgtag = '<span class="thumbnail pull-left"><img src="' + img[0].src.replace('/s' + uh + '/', '/s' + img_thumb_width + '/') + '" width="' + img_thumb_width + 'px" height="' + img_thumb_height + 'px"/></span>';
    summ = summary_img;
}

var summary = imgtag + '<p>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML, summ) + '</p>';
div.innerHTML = summary;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the number inside with something like:

```
replace(/\/s[0-9]+\//, '/s' + image_size + '/')
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nfDea/

Another option is to capture the beginning and end only, in order to concatenate:

```
replace(/(\/s)[0-9]+(\/)/, "$1" + image_size + "$2");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nfDea/1/

If you are actually referring to a variable called `uh`, then you need to use the following:

```
var re = new RegExp("/s(" + uh + ")/");
a = a.replace(re, "/s" + image_size + "/");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nfDea/4/

or

```
var re = new RegExp("(/s)" + uh + "(/)");
a = a.replace(re, "$1" + image_size + "$2");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nfDea/3/

Comment: Thanks the first one solved my question!

Answer (score -1):

```
var reg = new RegExp('/s' + uh);
...
img[0].src.replace(reg, '/s' + img_thumb_width + '/')
```